# Is it possible to create visual plugins in Netbeans, with Java?

Tags: java, user-interface, netbeans, plugins, netbeans-plugins

Is it possible to create visual plugins in Netbeans, with Java?

With visual plugins, I mean plugins/extra features that can parse code and display visual representations. Of course, with me coding the visuals.

I have searched for it, but I don't know what to search for.

In other words; Is there a way of creating a GUI plugin for internal use in Netbeans, written in Java(with/without frameworks)?

Comment: You're right - that was short =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. The NetBeans IDE is built on the NetBeans Platform:

https://netbeans.org/kb/trails/platform.html

https://netbeans.org/features/platform/